# 'withAlert' is showing "Objects are not valid as React Child" Error

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-alert` and I am getting an error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: object with
> keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead.
> in Unknown (at App.js:24)
> in Provider (at App.js:21)
> in Provider (at App.js:20)
> in App (at src/index.js:12)
> in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11) "
> The 'Unknown' is my Alerts component which I was testing out to see if it shows errors as an alert.

Alert.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export class Alerts extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.alert.show("It works")
  }
  render() {
      return (
         <Fragment />
      );
  }  
}
export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

App.js:

```
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: "top center",
};

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvier template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
            <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Alerts />
            <div className="container">
                <Dashboard />
            </div>
            </Fragment>
        </AlertProvier>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I remove the `withAlert` from `export default withAlert(Alerts)` inside my `Alerts.js`, the errors are gone but obviously, I can't see the errors.

What shall I do to fix this and use react-alert properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for your Higher Order Component is just a little off. You'll want:

```
withAlert()(Alerts);
```

Keep in mind Higher Order Components are functions that return functions, so you'll need to invoke what's returned.

Comment: Thanks buddy! That was a very silly mistake! It works now. As you said I didn't use the () after withAlerts. Silly me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're so welcome! Be sure to accept the answer when you get a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
withAlert(Alerts)
```

by this

```
withAlert()(Alerts)
```